# Why can't I allow access to port 22 on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: firewall

I can't seem to figure out why port 22 will never let me ssh into my laptop. Here's what I'm trying:

```
ryan@gigantic-laptop:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

22                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
22                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)

ryan@gigantic-laptop:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Or if I try to disable:

```
ryan@gigantic-laptop:~$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
ryan@gigantic-laptop:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
ryan@gigantic-laptop:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
ryan@gigantic-laptop:~$ ssh 127.0.0.1
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ryan@gigantic-laptop:~$ sudo nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-02-23 18:14 PST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000016s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
631/tcp open  ipp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to install `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Comment: I have open-sshserver and still can't get port 22 open.